# Stencil js: update DOM element outside the component

Tags: stenciljs

I'm in the process of migrating some legacy pages to web components using StencilJS, so I'm in a situation where some elements are already handled with StencilJS, some are not, and migrating everything will take quite some time.

In this context I need to be able to update the contents of a target div not managed with StencilJS from a StencilJS component. This div is in a totally different branch of the DOM and it's impossible to move it into the component without rethinking the entire page.

So from my component I need to be able to do something like this:

```js
render() {
  const target = document.getElementById(this.targetDiv);
  if (target) {
    target.innerHTML = jsxToString(this.renderDivContents()) // obviously this doesn't work
  }
}

renderDivContents() {
    return (<p>Some JSX stuff</p>)
}
```

So, in other words I need to compile the JSX template immediately into a string. I'm not sure how to do that with StencilJS and if it is even possible. I'm under the impression that there is a way to achieve that because it looks very similar to what we do in tests, but all the resources I find on the topic are for JSX with React and does not really help with StencilJS

If this is not the correct approach, what do you suggest? I know injecting HTML into a DOM element is not ideal, but I'm just trying to find a temporary solution to be able to release my changes gradually.

PS: I know I can also use an overlay approach (generate a div into the component and give it the same position and size than the target div), but this sounds even uglier than innerHTML. This is not the answer I expect.

Comment: I found a solution, I generate the contents in a hidden div inside the component then just copy it to the target div in `componentDidUpdate`

That said, I'm still curious if it's possible to resolve a JSX template into a string

Comment: Just an idea: you could do whatever you do in `renderDivContents` in a Stencil component and then use DOM manipulations to insert your component into the target element, e. g. `document.querySelector('#target-div').appendChild('my-component')`.

Comment: About your question of turning the JSX template into a string, that's not easily possible because JSX gets turned into a bunch of nested `h(...)` calls. Afaik it would only be possible to turn it into a string if it was at build time, which is what server-side rendering would do. Not sure anything is exposed as a public API there though.